# Blazor equivalent to @Url.Action or @Html.ActionLink

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

In ASP.NET MVC, whenever you have a controller and an action in it, you could dynamically generate a link to it in a razor page like:

```
Url.Action("ProductController", "Index", new { id = "123" })
```

and this would return a string containing the path to that action with the specified route values:

```
/Product/123
```

Isn't there a similar method in Blazor where you could give it the component's name and route values:

```
Url.Component("ProductPage", new { id = "123" })
```

and get the path?

```
/Product/123
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `NavigationManager`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager?view=aspnetcore-6.0. Inject that and you can do it. I am not sure if you can pass the route values as an object, though or if you'll need to make something like a `NameValueCollection` and use the `Tostring()` method on it.

In short, something like:

```cs
@inject NavigationManager NavManager;

// Markup here

@code {

    public void MyMethod() {
        var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        var myUrl = "https://localhost:5000/somewhere/";
        // fill data
        NavManager.NavigateTo(myUrl + nameValueCollection.ToString(), false);
    }

}
```